# Jenkins with SSL over Docker

Tags: docker, ssl

I am trying to set up a Jenkins with SSL over Docker

```
sudo docker run --name trial  -d -p 443:8443  -p 50003:50000 -v /net/host/fs0/temp:/var/jenkins_home -httpPort=-1 -httpsPort=8443 -httpsKeyStore=/local/home/jenkins_keystore.jks -httpsKeyStorePassword=<password> --restart unless-stopped <ImageID>
```

The container is created but I do not find the jenkins in my browser with 
`https://< hostname >:443`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong order in your flags. All application-related flags need to be set after the ImageID and all docker-related flags before that.

```
sudo docker run --name trial -d -p 443:8443 -p 50003:50000 -v /net/host/fs0/temp:/var/jenkins_home --restart unless-stopped <ImageID> -httpPort=-1 -httpsPort=8443 -httpsKeyStore=/local/home/jenkins_keystore.jks -httpsKeyStorePassword=<password>
```